# Delete all debugger directives while webpack building

Tags: javascript, webpack, deployment, vuejs2, build

Is it possible to delete all `debugger` directives during the process of building to deploy the production code?
I have a vue app here.
I mean, while running the build command in webpack (in a vue app), is it possible to make webpack delete all debugger directives?

Comment: Have you looked at something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip?

Comment: @jonrsharpe... it´s strange how it deals with the requirement and it´s very old package.

Comment: @jonrsharpe... I´ve found that the uglify-js webpack plugin does have this option (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) I think it´s a more elegant solution